# How to Merge 2 Table cells in 'Google Slide' using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I tried to merge the 2 table cells in **Google Slide**, It's throwing the Error of *TypeError: Cannot find function merge in object TableCell. (line 47, file "Tester")*

**My sample function is**:

```
function googleSlideCellsMerge(){
    var table=SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides()[0].getTables()[0];

    var row = table.getRow(1);
    var cell1 = row.getCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.getCell(1);

    var mergeCell = cell2.merge();

    Logger.log(mergeCell);
}
```

In the above example, I tried to merge the 2 cells of Row 1.

I think the above code works with the **Google Docs**, but It's not for me with **Google Slide**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to merge cells of a table on the Slides using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script? Unfortunately, in the current stage, merging cells of a table cannot be achieved using Slides Service, yet. But when Slides API is used, it can be achieved.

**Before you use this script, [please enable Slides API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).**

#### Sample script:

```
var slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
var table = slide.getSlides()[0].getTables()[0];
var resource = {requests:[{mergeTableCells: {
  objectId: table.getObjectId(),
  tableRange: {
    location: {rowIndex: 0, columnIndex: 0},
    rowSpan: 2,
    columnSpan: 2
  }
}}]};
Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate(resource, slide.getId());
```

- In this sample script, the cells of a table of the 1st slide are merged.

  - When A1Notation is used, there is a table of "A1:C3", and the cells of "A1:B2" are merged.
- When you want to merge the 2 cells of Row 1, please modify `rowSpan` from `2` to `1`.

#### Result:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

#### References:

- [Slides Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/)
- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [presentations.batchUpdate of Slides API](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate)
- [MergeTableCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#mergetablecellsrequest)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: This is working once the **whole table is updated**, 
but I'm going to call slide API after Table data **update of every row**.

`for firstRow to LastRow{
  rowDataUpdation(firstRow);
  mergePropertyCall(firstRow);
};`

In this case, I'm getting the Error _The object (TableObject ID) could not be found_.

Comment: @sarath About your new issue, unfortunately, I cannot understand about ``for firstRow to LastRow{ rowDataUpdation(firstRow); mergePropertyCall(firstRow); };``. I would like to confirm your new issue. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information and your current script. Because when this answer is changed for your new question, it might make users confuse. And also I think that your new question might be useful for other users. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue. I'm glad.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately right now Google does not offer the possibility to merge cells in Google Slides tables through Apps Script. You can see here that a corresponding feature request has been submitted already:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/114200118

If you give the request a star, indicating your interest in the feature - this will increase the visibility of the impact of the feature. 
In the meantime you can try a workaround, e.g. copying the table to Google Sheets or Google Docs, merging the cells there and copy the table back.